# Pylance reports unbound variable when exit path is wrapped in a function, how to prevent?

Tags: python, pylance

Toy example:

```
import logging
import sys

def log_exit(
    msg: str | Exception
) -> None:
    logging.error("error, msg {}".format(msg))
    sys.exit(1)
     
try:
    a = 1
except Exception as e:
    log_exit(e)

b = a + 1


try:
    c = 1
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("error, msg {}".format(e))
    sys.exit(1)
    
d = c + 1
```

Pylance will warn me that, in the statement `b = a + 1`, `a` is possibly unbound. This only occurs when the path leading to `sys.exit()` is wrapped in a function, i.e. not in the second example with `c` and `d`. In my real code, on exit I need to do a few things e.g. close a connection to a database, and I don't want to repeat myself every time, but I also don't want Pylance to be telling me all my variables might be unbound, when indeed they're not. How can I avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does a `try.. except.. else` structure work for you? For example, moving `b = a+1` into an `else` block should avoid the possibility in Pylance's eyes of `a` being unbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `log_exit` function return hint should be `Never` instead of `None`.

https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/typing.html#typing.Never

That way, Pylance will know the function never returns (!= returns `None`).

It will also allow VSCode to dim any code unconditionally placed after a never returning function.

```py
from typing import Never

def log_exit(
    msg: str | Exception
) -> Never:
    logging.error("error, msg {}".format(msg))
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

PyLance basically considers that if a variable is declared in a `try` block, then that block could be skipped and the variable could therefore be undeclared. That's a quite simple check, that does not follow functions as much as you would like it to do, so sometimes there are false warnings.

What I would do in your place is declare the variables outside of any `try` block, even if you give them their values inside of it:

```py
import logging
import sys

def log_exit(
    msg: str | Exception
) -> None:
    logging.error("error, msg {}".format(msg))
    sys.exit(1)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = -1

    try:
        a = 1
    except Exception as e:
        log_exit(e)

    b = a + 1

    c = -1

    try:
        c = 1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("error, msg {}".format(e))
        sys.exit(1)
        
    d = c + 1
```

Here, I set a mock value to them that could be used for debugging: if `a` is still `-1` after my execution, that means its actual value has not been set.
(I also added a `main` function here, by the way).

As @slothrop suggested in comments, you also could use an `else` block: if no exceptions are raised, then execute something:

```py
import logging
import sys

def log_exit(
    msg: str | Exception
) -> None:
    logging.error("error, msg {}".format(msg))
    sys.exit(1)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        a = 1
    except Exception as e:
        log_exit(e)
    else:
        b = a + 1

    try:
        c = 1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("error, msg {}".format(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        d = c + 1
```